# How do I create a nested json object from a list with each item named by its unique ID

Tags: c#, json

I have been trying to get a JSON result to look like the below desired outcome. I am only able to return a list of items without the parent ID shown below; does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this result using generic objects?

```
{
  "items": {
    "567": {
      "id": "567",
      "url": "",
      "title": "Pay with Prepaid Credit",
      "desc": "Desc for paying for your order"
    },
    "568": {
      "id": "568",
      "url": "",
      "title": "Title Here",
      "desc": "Description here"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the following object models:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<ItemObject> items { get; set; }           
}

public class ItemObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string desc{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) with a custom [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) (and C# 7 features):

```
public class RootObjectConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = new RootObject();

        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(RootObject.items), out object obj) && obj is Dictionary<string, object> items)
        {
            result.items = new List<ItemObject>(items.Count);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                result.items.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<ItemObject>(item.Value));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null; // or throw
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        if (obj is RootObject rootObject)
        {
            var nestedDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var item in rootObject.items)
            {
                nestedDict[item.id] = item;
            }

            result[nameof(RootObject.items)] = nestedDict;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes => new List<Type> { typeof(RootObject) }.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Example usage:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] {new RootObjectConverter()});

var rootObject = new RootObject
{
    items = new List<ItemObject>
    {
        new ItemObject { id = "567", url = "", title = "Pay with Prepaid Credit", desc = "Desc for paying for your order" },
        new ItemObject {id = "568", url = "", title = "Title Here", desc = "Description here"}
    }
};

string json = serializer.Serialize(rootObject);
RootObject backToRootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

This produces the JSON you asked for in `json`:

```
{
   "items":{
      "567":{
         "id":"567",
         "url":"",
         "title":"Pay with Prepaid Credit",
         "desc":"Desc for paying for your order"
      },
      "568":{
         "id":"568",
         "url":"",
         "title":"Title Here",
         "desc":"Description here"
      }
   }
}
```

Obviously this is not a properly tested solution and doesn't take every little edge case into account, so take it with a grain of salt, but it might help you. Also I suggest checking Json.NET library from Newtonsoft, I haven't looked into it, but I'm sure it can be achieved with that as well and possibly easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `items` property in your `RootObject` class from a `List<ItemObject>` a to `Dictionary<string, ItemObject>` then you will get the results you want.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, ItemObject> items { get; set; }
}
```

To convert your existing list of items to a dictionary you can use the [`ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
RootObject root = new RootObject { items = listOfItems.ToDictionary(i => i.id) };
```

Here is a demo using Json.Net (but will also work with `JavaScriptSerializer`): https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEjPeI